# Query to get change in value day-over-day?

Tags: mysql, graphing

I have some historical data in a MySQL database, and I'm making graphs of it. Currently, my graphs look like this:

[image]

I'd like, however, to get the *change* in the value over time - i.e. show the change since the last measurement. Something like this (obviously the data isn't correct):

[image]

How can I write a MySQL query that gets the delta of a value when compared with the previous row?

This is my current query, with help from juergen d:

```
SELECT `timestamp`, total_users, total_users - @prev AS col1, @prev := total_users, FROM stats, (select @prev := 0) p GROUP BY DAY(`timestamp`), floor(HOUR(`timestamp`)/2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Generally

Use a variable that holds the last records' value to calculate the delta

```
select some_column, 
       some_column - @prev as delta, 
       @prev := some_column
from your_table, (select @prev := 0) p
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e82b/1)

### The actual query

```
SELECT DAY(`timestamp`) as day_ts, 
       floor(HOUR(`timestamp`)/2) as hour_ts
       sum(total_users)
       sum(total_users) - @prev AS col1, 
       @prev := sum(total_users)
FROM stats, (select @prev := 0) p 
GROUP BY day_ts, hour_ts
```

Comment: So `@prev` is smart and selects the same column in the last row?

Comment: It will be compared to the current row and then set to the value of the current row. In the next row it contains the last value. You compare it, then set the current value and so on

Comment: @Undo, first time prev = 0, then it gets set, when the next row get processed by the query it's now the previous value, gets used to calculate the delta and then gets set to the value of the current row. Think while loop iterating through an array

Comment: Ok, great! I'm trying to just tack on my group clause `GROUP BY DAY('timestamp'), floor(HOUR('timestamp')/2)`, but it throws a bad syntax near `'FROM stats, (select @prev := 0) GROUP BY DAY('timestamp'), floor(HOUR('timestamp'`

Comment: You need an alias for the subselect. Notice the `p` in my query?

Comment: I've tried to figure it out, but I wasn't able to - how can I group it by day, etc?

Comment: Can you post your complete query?

Comment: `SELECT 'timestamp', total_users, total_users - @prev AS col1, @prev := total_users, FROM stats, (select @prev := 0) p GROUP BY DAY('timestamp'), floor(HOUR('timestamp')/2)` (edited post too)

Comment: I updated my answer, but without the table structure, example data, expected output and a short explanation what you want to do, it is kind of guessing.